# Custom Bad Gateway Page with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to serve a custom "Bad Gateway" error page in Nginx?

Similar to having custom 404 pages.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/194301) (works for me on nginx/1.2.1)

Comment: The default config for my centos was /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html mentioned in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's similar to setting up the custom 404 pages.  Here's what I've got.

```
#site-wide error pages
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your answer and come back to update the thread

Comment: This didn't work for me, I wonder if the behaviour has changed in newer versions of nginx. I tried [these slightly different instructions](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189334) and got it working.

Comment: Confirmed. That doesn't work. This shouldn't be the correct answer.

Comment: What file do you need to add these lines to? And where is that file located?

Comment: This does not worked for me, but following the exact steps mentioned by @jack-desert worked.

Comment: You need to add these files to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf, as for where the files are located, it will be mentioned in the config file, for me it is /usr/share/nginx/html/

Comment: Doesn't work. Can we request for more updated answer

Answer (score 68):

There are three pieces that must be in place in order for your custom error page to display instead of the generic "Bad Gateway" error.

1. You must create an html file named something like "500.html" and place it in the root. In the case of Rails running behind Nginx, this means putting it at public/500.html.
2. You must have a line in your config file that points at least the 502 errors to that 500.html page like this:

   ```
   error_page 502 /500.html;
   ```
3. You must have a location block for /500.html in your config file. If your root is already defined, this block can be empty. But the block must exist nonetheless.

   ```
   location /500.html{
   }
   ```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I can confirm it worked for me and I could make a custom 502 error response following the exact steps above. The current accepted answer is misleading and don't work.

Comment: Sweet. You can also specify `root` in the location block if you want the error page to live in a different place.

Comment: How do I also show for all 500 errors? error_page 500 501 502 503 504 /500.html;

Answer (score 25):

using debian (9.3 stretch actually) i did following steps:

- create `/var/www/html/502.html` with the content for the 502 error page
- edit `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mywebsite.conf`

so it looks similar like this:

```
server {
    listen 80; listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    error_page 502 /502.html;
    location /502.html {
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

- then restarted nginx using `service nginx restart`

Comment: Of all the answers to this question, this is the only answer I found to be both accurate AND _COMPLETE_. There were so many details left out of the other answers that I could not get them to work. The details would be nothing for someone familiar with Nginx configs, but I am not. This answer gave the precise things I needed to do to actually accomplish the goal of the OP.

Comment: The only thing is that if the 502.html file is missing... then you get a 404 instead of the default 502. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: how would you like to "fix" that? what would you expect? if the 502.html file is missing, you should remove the according configuration so the default 502 error page is shown.

Comment: Very useful answer! and here's a default 502.html template with utf-8 so you can use special characters normally 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Manutenção</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>HTML UTF-8 Reference</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<h1>App is in maintenance mode.</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Another one with decent styling: https://gist.github.com/pitch-gist/2999707

Answer (score 4):

While @Larsenal's answer is technically correct for the minimum configuration, there are common configurations that will make it not work. @Jack Desert's answer touches on this but doesn't provide a full explanation of why that's needed.

Suppose we have this configuration (simplified from @Jack).

```
error_page 502 504 /my-error-page.html;
```

What this is saying is, in the case of a 502 or 504 error internally, rewrite the original URI as `/my-error-page.html`.

What I think most people miss is that this then **goes through the same processing chain** that happens as if you requested that page directly. This means that it goes through all the same location block checks.

Since a common method of doing a reverse proxy on nginx is to configure a `location / {` block, that location matches `/my-error-page.html` and thus **nginx tries to use the proxy to serve the error file**. Since a common use case is serving a static file in the case that the backend is down, serving this error page from the backend will likely also fail, making nginx default to serving its own internal error page that we were trying to replace in the first place.

So, a common solution, the one @Jack Desert suggests, is to include another `location` block that will match the `/my-error-page.html` URL before the `location /` block. Note that the order of location blocks in nginx configuration has no effect; There is a very specific set of rules for picking precedence of location blocks based on the URL. That location block needs to have whatever is necessary to serve that file like any other static file that nginx might serve. This means a `root` directive is needed somewhere and that `/my-error-page.html` will be loaded relative to that (`root` can be set at nearly any level of the nginx configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

Type this in your terminal

```
cd /etc/nginx

sudo nano nginx.conf
```

and under http add these lines

```
    error_page 500 Path_to_your_custom_error_page;
    error_page 503 Path_to_your_custom_error_page;
    error_page 504 Path_to_your_custom_error_page;
```

Now restart nginx by typing this command:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Bingo now you can see custom error message on gateway error

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't say, but it's quite common to hit this problem when API's are behind an nginx pass through proxy, so in that case you want the response to be JSON not HTML.

My favorite approach is to just use the redirect functionality of the `error_page` directive to redirect back to an error page on the same site:

```
error_page 502 503 $scheme://$server_name/500.json;
```

It's one line, you can reuse the same `500.json` for different `location`'s, and there is no need for a mysterious empty `location`.  You place your error message in the `500.json` file at the root of your site.  I assume that you already have a `location / {...}` directive there that serves up static files.

You can of course use this same approach to serve an HTML error page too.

Comment: I use it to jam analytics tracking on for long term analysis. You can better grab the users cookie that way, then do javascript redirect.